# Hardware error, possibly related to CPU microcode?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cpu

As a bit of a newbie to this I was wondering if anyone would be able to help me diagnose a potential hardware problem.

Generally my system runs fine but with some memory/cpu intensive python code the system has completely crashed. The main error code I can find in my log is the following:

```
mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 11: Machine Check: 0 Bank 0: b200000000070005
 mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 
 mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:50654 TIME 1568095380 SOCKET 0 APIC 18 microcode 200005e
```

Some googling has at least led me to check if I have the latest microcode (I do) and whether my system is generally up to date (it is). Overall my system runs fine and the code hasn't caused any errors on other machines so its definitely a system issue. Just not even sure where to start resolving it at this point..

My setup:
Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Intel i9-7940X @ 3.10GHz (14 core, 28 threads)
64GB RAM
ASUS ROG STRIX X299-E Gaming MB
GeForce GTX 1050i graphics

Comment: mcelog will show detailed information on K8 compatible processors, but I am not sure if your cpu is compatible with it.

Comment: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1005184 to help decode your *bank* info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that (at least for now) a BIOS flash solved the issue. Interpolating from other post in retrospect it might have been a kernel-BIOS mismatch that was causing the error in the first place, but only results in a system crash when all CPU's where being used.

Answer (score 0):

I recall that this may be related to thermal issues, since you mention CPU-intensive Python code that you ran before the crash. Can you reproduce the crash and can you monitor the CPU temperature(s)?

Comment: Tried that too but didn't seem an issue